# Flutter - Which identifier do I use to call classes?

Tags: flutter, dart, identifier, flutter-hive

There is an identifier that is needed to be passed for this to work but I am not sure what identifier has to be called. Can someone help?

I am needing to make it so when I press the button, it goes through all those working functions, and then takes the user to the next page `page_ApiBox()`.

I am getting an **"Expected Identifier, but got ,"** Error on the `Navigator.of(context)...` line.
I see that an identifier needs to be called inside of `page_ApiBox(apibox: )));` but I am not sure what identifier is supposed to be called. `Null` does not work.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(backgroundColor: Color(0xFF7E57C2),
            onPressed: () {
            final api_key_input = _apiKeyController.text;
            print('User API: $api_key_input');
            getApi();
              //var post = json.decode(response.body);                                      *UNCOMMENT LATER*
              // INSERT HERE: Store API Key Value in Encrypted Box.
              //   MOCK API RESPONSE-----------------                                       *DELETE LATER*
              print('Verification Successful');
              addApi(api_key_input);
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>page_ApiBox(apibox: ,)));

            label: Text('Verify'); floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat;},


class page_ApiBox extends StatefulWidget {
    const page_ApiBox({Key? key, required this.apibox,}) : super(key: key);
    final apiBox apibox;

    @override
    State<page_ApiBox> createState() => _page_ApiBoxState();
  }



  class _page_ApiBoxState extends State<page_ApiBox> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
          body: buildApiBox(context, widget.apibox)
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Add what error or problem are you getting?

Comment: Post has been updated.

Comment: This is where you error exist ```Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>page_ApiBox(apibox: ,)));``` You didn' supply any parameter for apibox.

Comment: You need to provide an object of apiBox which is created by you ... you need to add the buildApiBox method body if you are not aware of apiBox

Comment: That is exactly the question I'm asking.
page_ApiBox is already a defined class. (See my code)

My question is what identifier do I use to call the class?